# issue with scatter plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to get a scatter plot of 'Ages', so that I can later choose a machine learning algorithm to predict the 'Ages' absent in the dataset in a practise set of Titanic for machine learning.

```
train_data = fullset.iloc[:len(traindf)]
test_data = fullset.iloc[len(traindf):]
trainplot = train_data['Age'].dropna(how = 'any')
trainplot = trainplot.astype(int)
trainplot.drop(labels = 0,inplace = True)
len(trainplot) -> o/p : 713
```

trainplot contains all the number of ages present in the dataset excluding all the NaNs.

```
sns.regplot(x='trainplot.index' , y =  'trainplot', data = 'trainplot')
```

when trying to plot with the above code I get an error saying **string indices must be integers.** I have even removed the 0s present in the trainplot but the error still persists. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your call to regplot does not look right. (1) Using the same argument for y and data itself looks strange. (2) data can't be a string, it's a DataFrame! (-> ```data=trainplot```)
 (3) Check out the available columns in your df, as you call for ```trainplot.index``` which needs a column exactly called like that.

Comment: I have checked it. it says strings, Series or vectors can be put in the x,y parameters provided data parameter is provided. what alternative can you suggest instead of trainplot.index?

Comment: First correct your usage of data!